# Inequality $(a+b)^2 + (a+b+4c)^2\ge \frac{kabc}{a+b+c}$ for $a,b,c \in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Find biggest constans k such that  $(a+b)^2 + (a+b+4c)^2\ge \frac{kabc}{a+b+c}$ is true for any $a,b,c \in\mathbb{R}$

Could you check up my solution? I'm not sure it's ok -

$(a+b)^2 + (a+b+4c)^2 \ge 0$

and

$0\ge \frac{kabc}{a+b+c}$

so

$0 \ge k$

Comment: The RHS is definitely not less than $0$ in general.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense when $a+b+c=0$ and is wrong anyway if you allow the variables to be negative. Don't you mean $a,b,c\in\mathbb R_+$?

Comment: no I didn't mean

Answer (score 5):

We need to worry only about $a+b+c> 0^\dagger$ and the inequality is homogeneous, so we may set $a+b+c=1$ and $c \in (0, 1]$

Then we have $ab \le \frac14(1-c)^2$ and we need to find largest $k$ satisfying 
$$(1-c)^2+(1+3c)^2 \ge \frac{k}4 c(1-c)^2 \implies \frac{k}4 \le \frac1c+\frac1c\left(\frac{1+3c}{1-c}\right)^2$$

Minimising that gets you $k \le 100$ and when $a=b=\frac25, c=\frac15$, we have equality, so $k=100$ is indeed the largest possible.

---

$^\dagger$ if $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$, cases with $a+b+c=0$ or $\dfrac{abc}{a+b+c} \to \infty$ occur and no $k$ will satisfy the inequality.

Comment: +1 Although I think we need to worry about $a+b+c\le 0$. For one if $a+b+c=0$, it doesn't even make sense, so it can't hold. But it gets worse, e.g. for $a=b=1$ and $c\searrow -2$, the RHS goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: @user2345215 when $a+b+c=0$, the question doesn't exist / make sense.  For $a=b=1$ and $c \to -2$, the RHS is negative, i.e. $\to -\infty$ as long as $a+b+c=1$, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: ​@Macavity You are wrong. Firstly, it can't be true if it doesn't make sense, that the usual convention. It specifially says for **all** $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, not for all such that $a+b+c\ne 0$. E.g. it's not true that $\forall x\in\mathbb R, \frac xx=1$. And I should have written $c\nearrow -2$, see for yourself: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+c%2F%282%2Bc%29+from+-3+to+-1

Comment: @user2345215 If you interpret that the question should answer for $a+b+c=0$ as well that is a comment you can put on the question itself - there is no point in discussing any answer with that case included.  Best if that point is put to the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Using $\text{arithmetic mean} \geq \text{geometric mean}$, we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2&=&(a+b)^2+(a+2c+b+2c)^2 \\
&\geq& \big(2\sqrt{ab}\big)^2+\big(2\sqrt{2ac}+2\sqrt{2b}\big)^2 \\
&=& 4ab+8ac+8bc+16c\sqrt{ab}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Therefore
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2}{abc}(a+b+c)&\geq&\frac{4ab+8ac+8bc+16c\sqrt{ab}}{abc}(a+b+c)\\
&=&\Bigg(\frac4c+\frac8b+\frac8a+\frac{16}{\sqrt{ab}}\Bigg)(a+b+c)\Bigg(\frac a 2+\frac a 2+\frac b 2+\frac b 2+c\Bigg)\\
&\geq&8\Bigg(5\sqrt[5]{\frac1{2a^2b^2c}}\Bigg)\Bigg(5\sqrt[5]{\frac{a^2b^2c}{2^4}}\Bigg)\\
&=& 100
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Hence,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
k &\leq& \frac{(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2}{abc}(a+b+c)\\
&\leq& 100\tag*{$\square$}
\end{eqnarray}
$$